# EF4 Code First with existing DB and one to one/one to many on SAME type

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first, one-to-one

After countless hours I finally managed to get the fluent api settings to map our complex existing SQL DB to POCO classes. There is one thing which I do not get to work and I am wondering if it might not be supported.

Class Power has:

```
List<Transaction> PowerTransactions;
Transaction LastPowerTransaction;
int PowerTransactionId;
```

Transactions is one to many where the Transaction Table has a FK pointing to Power.PowerID, that works fine.

Power has column PowerTransactionId and  FK pointing to the TransactionId in the Transaction Table.

I set in fluent API:

Power has optional Last Transaction with required power

```
HasOptional(x => x.LastPowerTransaction).WithRequired(x => x.PowerLastPowerTransaction).Map(x =>     x.MapKey("PowerTransactionId"));
```

Powers TransactionId is 123 and PowerID is 1, when selecting Power.LastPowertransaction I get the transaction with id 1 not 123.

As the many to many does a select .. from PowerTransaction where PowerID=1, the One to One does the same thing instead of select .. from PowerTransaction where PowerID=123.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Why didn't you just use the free Entity Framework Power Tools to reverse engineer the database?  You would have been done in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystere Man's comment was not the real answer but using the mentioned tool led to the correct answer. EF4 code first only does one to one relationships with shared primary keys. The reveres engineering revealed this as NO one to one was created. Therefore my fluent mapping was wrong. This is a limitation in EF4 code first where one has to work around using one to one as "fake" one to many if the existing db does not use shared primary keys.